# Why do I get "ghcjs-boot: command not found"?

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghcjs

I've installed ghcjs by the command

```
cabal install ./ghcjs ./ghcjs-prim
```

And I get something like

```
Updating documentation MyDir/Haskell/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.8.3/index.html
```

for my last line.

But when I tried this command

```
ghcjs-boot --dev
```

I got `-bash: ghcjs-boot: command not found`
What's the problem?

Comment: Do you have ~/.cabal/bin in your PATH?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Mmm... Sorry but how to check whether it's in my path?

Comment: @YiyueWang `echo $PATH` in your terminal (it will print the content of your `PATH` variable - look if you can find the path to your `home-directory/.cabal/bin` in there)

Comment: @CarstenKönig Thank you very much! I've solved the problem now :) And do you know how I can close this question?

Comment: as you found the answer yourself you might write your own answer here - then you have to wait a bit (no clue how long sorry) and then you can mark your own answer - or you can ask @MichaelSnoyman to write a short answer you can then accept instead if you want to give him some cudos

Comment: if you want I can flag it to close too but then 4 others have to do as well

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Do you mind changing your comment to an answer so that I can mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting my comment as an answer by request:

Do you have ~/.cabal/bin in your PATH?